# Splitting a string for last occurrence a character

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a String with a format like this :

```
"abc=cde,dfe=lk,f,sss=f,d,s"
```

I'd like to recover these values in a map by using the first set of characters as a key and the second ones as value.

For example

- key: `abc`, value: `cde`
- key: `dfe`, value: `lk,f`
- key: `sss`, value: `f,d,s`

So splitting these values for the last occurrence of ",".

Any ideas on how to do it?

I tried with regex and Stringtokenizer but I can't manage to recover just the last occurrence of ","

Comment: Please paste your relevant section of code in your Question for others to identify where lies the exact problem.

Comment: You could split the string by split(",") to get the groups, and then interate on those to split("=").

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex (could possibly be optimized):

```
,(?=(?:(?!,).)*=)
```

(see on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7JcJmu/1))

This matches a `,` which has no subsequent `,` until the next `=`.

Comment: @Marconno : You are correct. Upvoting.   I used the same technique.

Comment: @Cetriolo no problem. If that solved your question, please mark this or one of the other answers as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex for this.

**Full Code** :

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        String input = "abc=cde,dfe=lk,f,sss=f,d,s";
        String[] arrOfStr = input.split(",(?=(?:(?!,).)*=)");
        
        HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<arrOfStr.length;i++) {
            String[] temp = arrOfStr[i].split("=");
            properties.put(temp[0], temp[1]);           
            
        }           
        System.out.println("Input String     : " +input);
        System.out.println("\nFinal properties : ");
    
        properties.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
        System.out.println("key = " +entry.getKey() + " :: value = " + entry.getValue());  
     });

    }    
}
```

**Output** :

```
Input String     : abc=cde,dfe=lk,f,sss=f,d,s

Final properties : 
key = dfe :: value = lk,f
key = sss :: value = f,d,s
key = abc :: value = cde
```

Answer (score 0):

Full Code :

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "abc=cde,dfe=lk,f,sss=f,d,s";
        String[] parts = text.split(",");
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String key = null;
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (parts[i].contains("=")) {
                if (key != null) {
                    map.put(key, value.toString());
                    value.setLength(0);
                }
                String[] innerParts = parts[i].split("=");
                key = innerParts[0];
                value.append(innerParts[1]);
            } else {
                value.append(',').append(parts[i]);
            }
        }
        map.put(key, value.toString());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }   
    }    
}
```

Output :

abc=cde

dfe=lk,f

sss=f,d,s